# Get text between complex tags in PHP

Tags: php, regex, tags, expression

I'm trying to get text from in between 2 html tags, only the difficulty is that the tag can differ from name.

I'll explain into detail:

```
<icon displayid="62115">inv_helmet_130</icon>
```

I have to get the

> inv_helmet_130

But the **displayid** of the tag can differ, any ideas on how to solve this? Perhaps with a regular explression but I'm not good at those.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse XML. Have you considered an XML parser?

Comment: differ? so if its not "62115", then you don't want to get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simple HTML DOM Parse](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)r should be able to handle that:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

foreach($html->find('icon') as $element) 
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
```

You can single them out like this:

```
echo $html->find('icon', 0)->innertext; // get me the first
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** use a regular expressions for dealing with HTML.

Use something specifically designed for XML/HTML like [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) instead. It is already part of [PHP's libraries](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp).

The XPath expression you want is going to something along the lines of this,

```
//icon/text()
```

Which reads, "Select the text from any `icon` element in the document, regardless of its id or parents."

Answer (score 0):

Since `<icon>` is not a valid HTML tag, I presume you're working with XML or some other markup language. PHP has a pretty handy extension to deal with XML:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?><icon displayid="62115">inv_helmet_130</icon>');
echo (string)$xml[0];

?>
```

The exact code, of course, depends on your exact string. As suggested, an xpath search can do the trick.